# scss-lint - how config the default.yml?

Tags: gulp

I'm using [scss-lint](https://github.com/causes/scss-lint) with [gulp.js](http://gulpjs.com/) in my project and I want to add some configurations to my local `scss-lint` fork.
In the documentation of `scss-lint` it's says that I can add a configuration by creating a file named `.scss-lint.yml` in the styles directory, so I do:

```
scss_files: 'src/styles/**/*.scss'

NestingDepth:
    enabled: true
    max_depth: 4

SelectorDepth:
  enabled: true
  max_depth: 4
```

But when I run `gulp` the configurations just not apply. How can I make my configuration work?

Comment: Can you show the related gulp task?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to place your `.scss-lint.yml` config file either in the root directory of the working project for local use, or indeed in your **Home Directory** for global use.

To find the path of your Home Directory [you can reference this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory#Default_home_directory_per_operating_system).

**Using scss-lint with Sublime Text?**

Be sure to restart the Sublime Text to activate your `.scss-lint.yml` config file.